# Taking the limit of n(e^1/n −1) as n approaches infinity then proving it by the squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital, formal-proofs

Instead of using L'Hospital's rule can this be proved by using the definition of the limit and or the squeeze theorem.

Comment: What have you tried? You could solve this quickly using the Taylor series for the exponential.

Comment: I have tried using a epilson on two arguement and the Taylor series didn't work out too well for me. I'm trying to prove this as apart of a problem set for my real analysis class and I think the necessary proof is from a squeeze theorem arguement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Mean Value Theorem to deduce that $1+u+u^{2}/2\leq e^{u}\leq 1+u+u^{2}$ for $0\leq u\leq 1/2$, then for $n\geq 2$, we have $1/n\leq 2$ and hence $1+(1/n)+1/(2n^{2})\leq e^{1/n}\leq 1+(1/n)+1/n^{2}$, so $n(e^{1/n}-1)\rightarrow 1$.

The use of Mean Value Theorem here:

Let $\varphi(u)=1+u+u^{2}-e^{u}$, $0\leq u\leq 1/2$, then for $0<u\leq 1/2$, $\varphi(u)=\varphi(u)-\varphi(0)=\varphi'(\xi)u$, where $\xi$ lies in between $0$ and $u$.

Since $\varphi'(\xi)=1+2\xi-e^{\xi}$, we investigate the function $\eta(u)=1+2u-e^{u}$ for $0\leq u\leq 1/2$. Note that for $0<u\leq 1/2$, $\eta(u)=\eta(u)-\eta(0)=\eta'(\omega)u=(2-e^{\omega})u>0$ for some $\omega$ lies in between $0$ and $u$, in particular, $\omega$ lies in between $0$ and $1/2$.

So $\eta(\xi)>0$ and hence $\varphi'(\xi)=\eta(\xi)>0$, so $\varphi(u)>0$.

Comment: Could you please give more information a bit more how did you use the mean value theorem

Comment: Thank you very much is it possible to solve this by using a epilson on two arguement or by using the squeeze theorem?

Comment: My reasoning finally goes with Squeeze Theorem, just the middle with the aid of Mean Value Theorem, no? I see no hope in doing $\epsilon$-argument, as you know, we all are supposed to know the answer of the limit, and then running $\epsilon$-argument to confirm the accuracy, but not the other way around.

Comment: So how could we prove it by the squeeze theorem?

Comment: So $1+1/(2n)\leq n(e^{1/n}-1)\leq 1+1/n$ by the inequalities. Now $1+1/(2n)\rightarrow 1$ and $1+1/n\rightarrow 1$, so squeeze it, the limit is then $1$.

Comment: Would that be a full proof to answer this question using the squeeze theorem I feel like you would need a bit more?

Comment: Yes, that is enough, I don't see any gap. For Squeeze Theorem we have a rigorous proof, so it is totally safe to use that.

Comment: So once you have done that could you not just do a epilson arguement just for the sake of doing so.

Comment: Then the $\epsilon$-argument is in some sense the proof of Squeeze Theorem instantiating to this question, but why doing that? The point is that, Squeeze Theorem has proved in most of the textbooks.

Comment: True, thanks for the help!

Comment: Are there any other unique methods of forming a proof for this question?

Comment: What do you mean by other unique methods of forming a proof? Like what?

Comment: Well besides using the squeeze theorem or Mean value theorem and within the realm of real analysis

Comment: Actually Taylor series is the fastest way here.

Comment: @user284331 I'm not certain that Taylor's Theorem is the "fastest way."  See my solution as a fairly efficient way forward.

Answer (score 3):

In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities

$$1+x\le e^x\le \frac1{1-x}\tag 1$$

for $x<1$.

Letting $x=\frac1n$ for $n>1$ in $(1)$, subtracting $1$, and multiplying the result by $n$ reveals

$$1\le n(e^{1/n}-1)\le \frac{1}{1-\frac1n}$$

whence applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted result.

Comment: So how would you do this from the beginning without using that previous answer you gave

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn I would develop the inequalities in $(1)$ using the approach in the referenced answer or develop a different set of inequalities using other tools such as Taylor's Theorem.  Another approach would be to transform variables.

Comment: Yes, faster than Taylor one, thanks.

Comment: @user284331 You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn The tools I used were about as elementary as one can use to fulfill your request efficiently.  Tools:  Bernoulli's Inequality, the limit definition of the exponential function, arithmetic of inequalities, and the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.